# How to post to a PHP script using Prototype.js

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I'm brand new to prototype.js and trying to do a simple GET request to a PHP script. The Javascript show do the following:

1. Get the users latitude and longitude
2. Pass the lat/long to the doStuff() function
3. Pass the lat/long to my PHP script (savecoords.php) to be saved.

For some reason, it's like this code isn't even executing even though I am sure I'm using an HTML5 capable browser that implements the Geolocation API.  Here is the code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        doStuff(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    });
}

function doStuff(mylat, mylong) {
    new Ajax.Request('savecoords.php', {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: {
            'latitude': myLat,
            'long': myLong
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use your browser's console/debugger to set breakpoints in the Javascript and see if it really is being run. You cannot assume anything else until you know that is happening. If you have Firefox then get Firebug, if you have Chrome it is built in.

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure out why your function is not being called, you'll likely need to pass in an [error callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_geolocation#Handling_errors). For example:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(yourFunction, function (error) {
        console.log(error.message, error.code);
    });
}
```

This will provide you with the error code and message to narrow down why your function isn't being called. The `code` will return one of several values, and the `message` should provide greater detail. From the MDC page linked above:

> **UNKNOWN_ERROR (numeric value 0)**
>
> The location acquisition process failed due to an error not covered by the definition of any other error code in this interface.
>
> **PERMISSION_DENIED (numeric value 1)**
>
> The location acquisition process failed because the application origin does not have permission to use the Geolocation API.
>
> **POSITION_UNAVAILABLE (numeric value 2)**
>
> The position of the device could not be determined. One or more of the location providers used in the location acquisition process reported an internal error that caused the process to fail entirely.
>
> **TIMEOUT (numeric value 3)**
>
> The specified maximum length of time has elapsed before the implementation could successfully acquire a new Position object.

I'm sure that this doesn't solve your problem entirely, but it should give you the necessary insight to make some progress.